# setState in React no working inside event gridjs

Tags: reactjs, gridjs, gridjs-react

I am working with the `gridjs` library, which has a click event, when modifying a state it does not do so. any idea what it could be?

```
componentDidMount() {      
    this.consultaAPI();
    localStorage.removeItem("excludeIDS")
    this.grid.current.instance.on('cellClick', (...item) => {  
        console.log(this)
        if(typeof item[1].data === "boolean"){
            console.log(item)
            console.log(item[3]._cells[1].data)
            //console.log(row[1]._cells[1].data);
            let newID = JSON.stringify(item[3]._cells[1].data)

            if(item[1].data && this.state.todos){
                if(localStorage.getItem("excludeIDS")!=null){
                    let ids = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("excludeIDS"))
                    if(!ids.includes(newID)){
                        ids.push(newID)
                        localStorage.setItem("excludeIDS", JSON.stringify(ids))
                        console.log("add id")
                        this.setState({count:this.state.count-1})
                    }
                }else{
                    console.log("created collection")
                    let ids =[newID] 
                    localStorage.setItem("excludeIDS",JSON.stringify(ids))
                    this.setState({count:this.state.count-1})
                   
                }
            }else if(!item[1].data && this.state.todos){
                console.log("remove id of collections")
                let ids = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("excludeIDS"))
            
                ids.splice(ids.indexOf(newID),1)
                localStorage.setItem("excludeIDS",JSON.stringify(ids))
                this.setState({count:this.state.count+1})
            }
        }

 });
```

Comment: Can you provide the full working code of what's working and what is not working?

Comment: yes Simmi, https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-sid-iqiuog?file=/src/App.js   the idea is to update the button according to the selected checkbox